# Detect Leading Zero in String

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently trying to detect if a number has a leading zero.  Not sure what the best way is to detect that. An example would something like this "000445454"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`String.StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

*"Determines whether the beginning of this string instance matches a specified string."*

```
string numbers =  "000445454";
if (numbers.StartsWith("0"))
    //Do Something
```

Comment: I'd combine this with `Int32.TryParse()` if you aren't guaranteed your numbers will adhere to a given x digit format. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to detect a leading zero in a non empty "s" string is to compare its first element with the character '0':

s[0] == '0'

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "0";
if(str.StartsWith("0") && str.Length !=1) Console.WriteLine("false");
else Console.WriteLine("true");
```

if the string starts with `'0'` and if it has more than one character.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with c# syntax

But in **C++** in order to find **00, 05, 01** , i tend to do this:

We can find the index of first zero from left using

```
index = str.find('0');
```

And now check if index == 0 means leading ZERO and the length of string is greater than 1

```
if(index ==0 and str.length()>1){
    cout<<"Leading Zero";
}
```